# Issues of getting stuck into infinite loop while iterating through vectors

Tags: c++

I want to search through a vector of pairs and in order to do so..i am doing the following:

```
 vector<pair<double ,double> > vec_pairs;

 for(vector<unsigned int>::size_type j = 0; j != vec_pairs.size(); j++ )
        {
            if(vec_pairs[j].first==12.6)
            {
              int z=7;
              continue;
            }
        }
```

However my problem is...upon doing this...i am getting stuck in an infinite loop...
Can anyone help me in resolving the problem

Comment: Try changing `j!=vec_pairs.size()` to `j<vec_pairs.size()`.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I tried but still i am getting stuck into infinite loop

Comment: can you post the code inside the "if"?

Comment: Is it the whole code? do you modify j _inside_ the loop?

Comment: Are you sure this is where you're getting stuck?  Please show a complete, compileable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in the debugger? Does j go beyond the end of the array or does it reset to the start or get stuck on a certain value? What do you see if you cout << j << endl in the loop? These are some basic debugging things you should try first that may help lead you to the answer faster than you'll get a reply online :)

Comment: Also, you don't want to do floating-point comparisons with `==`.

Comment: Why aren't you using the iterator anyway? That may help you avoid this issue entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the code that you posted works well 'as it is'.

The only reason for such type of a code to go into infinite loop is to modify `j` inside the loop.

If you *increase*  `j` inside the loop, you will probably not get stuck because you will go out of bonds and might have your code crash.

```
for(vector<unsigned int>::size_type j = 0; j != vec_pairs.size(); j++ )
    {
        if(vec_pairs[j].first==12.6)
        {
            j++;//You will go out of vector bonds and might get an error here.
            continue;
        }
    }
```

However, if you do something like this:

```
for(vector<unsigned int>::size_type j = 0; j != vec_pairs.size(); j++ )
    {
        if(vec_pairs[j].first==12.6)
        {
            j--;//j is decreased each time you get in here, so you will be stuck on one element,
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Then you will get stuck inside, because when you go into the `if` statement (say, on element 7), `j` will decrease to 6, then you will `continue` the loop, `j` will increase back to 7, you will go inside the `if` again, and so on.

Comment: *"You will go out of vector bonds and get an error"* -- What kind of error?  Accessing a vector out of bounds is undefined behavior, so you can't be sure what will happen.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, yes, but it's likely that eventually your program will crash. I, for example, am having a segfault. However, you have your point, I\ll add "might" into the answer, thx.

Comment: std::vector operator[]  does not check for index bounds (at() does that). On a machine without memory protection (embedded device), increasing j can lead to an infinite loop as well.

Comment: @LutherBlissett, that's why I told the OP to change the loop exit condition from `j!=..` to `j<..` first in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in codepad. Check it [here](http://codepad.org/kPu3MjEx)! And it is working fine. Check the value of the variable `j` while debugging. As SingerOftheFall said, It might be getting decremented or reset somewhere. It can also go on an infinite loop if you are adding elements inside the loop which increase the value of `vec_pairs.size()` and the condition `j != vec_pairs.size()` will never be true in that case. Can't find anything wrong in the code you given.